# Even tough neither OpenGL nor SDL nor GLSL throws an error, there is no polygon that is drawn

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, sdl

I'm learning OpenGL with SDL2, and following [this tutorial](https://open.gl/introduction), and I have come to the Drawing Polygons -> Shaders part. However, although I have done everything that the tutorial have instructed, I'm not able to get any output from the code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

//Glew
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

//SDL headers
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_opengl.h"

//OpenGL headers
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glext.h>

//Constants
#define SCREEN_H 800
#define SCREEN_W 600
#define SCREEN_POS_X 0
#define SCREEN_POS_Y 0
#define SCREEN_FLAGS SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN|SDL_WINDOW_INPUT_FOCUS|SDL_WINDOW_MOUSE_FOCUS|SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL
//SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED
bool done = false;

SDL_Window * pWindow = NULL;
SDL_GLContext pGLContext = NULL;

//Methods
int Init(void );
void GameLoop();
void Render();
void EventTick();
void Quit(void );

    // Shader sources
const GLchar* vertexSource = R"glsl(
    #version 150 core
    in vec2 position;
    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
)glsl";

const GLchar* fragmentSource = R"glsl(
    #version 150 core
    out vec4 outColor;
    void main()
    {
        outColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    }
)glsl";


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Init();
    GameLoop();
    Quit();
    return 0;
}

int Init()
{
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return -1;
    }

    //Compatibility
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_STENCIL_SIZE, 8);

    pWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Main", SCREEN_POS_X, SCREEN_POS_Y, SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H, SCREEN_FLAGS);
    if (pWindow == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return -1;
    }

    pGLContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(pWindow);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();


    return 0;
}

void GameLoop()
{
    printf("%s\n", glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION));
    printf("%s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    float Vertices[] = {
        0.0f, 20.0f,
        20.0f, 0.0f,
        20.0f, 20.0f
    };

    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    //Check the vertex shader compilation
    GLint status_vertex;
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status_vertex);
    if (status_vertex != GL_TRUE)
    {
        char buffer[512];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, buffer);
        fprintf(stdout, "Vertex Shader: %s\n", buffer);
    }

    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    //Check the fragment shader compilation
    GLint status_fragment;
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status_fragment);
    if (status_fragment != GL_TRUE)
    {
        char buffer[512];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, buffer);
        fprintf(stdout, "Fragment Shader: %s\n", buffer);
    }

    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    if (shaderProgram == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "glGetError: %u\n", glGetError());
    }
    glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "position");
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glBindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "outColor");
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
    glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);

    GLint program_linked;
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &program_linked);
    if (program_linked != GL_TRUE)
    {
        GLsizei log_length = 0;
        GLchar message[1024];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 1024, &log_length, message);
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", message);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "glGetError (End): %u\n", glGetError());
    fprintf(stderr, "SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    while(!done)
    {
        EventTick();
        Render();
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "glGetError (End): %u\n", glGetError());
    fprintf(stderr, "SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());

    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);
}

void Render()
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(pWindow);

}

void EventTick()
{
    SDL_Event s_GameEngEvent;
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&s_GameEngEvent))
    {
        switch(s_GameEngEvent.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
            {
                fprintf(stdout, "SQL is quitting...\n");
                done = true;
            }break;

            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            {
                switch(s_GameEngEvent.key.keysym.scancode)
                {
                    case SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE:
                        {
                        fprintf(stdout, "SQL is quitting...\n");
                        done = true;
                        }break;
                    default:
                    break;
                }
            }break;
        }
    }

}

void Quit(void )
{
    //Destructions...
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(pGLContext);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(pWindow);
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

I have several parts of the code one by one, and compared to the original [code](https://open.gl/content/code/c2_triangle.txt), but found nothing.

I would really appreciated if someone could check where the problematic part is. I mean I know I did not try to write a good code above, I was trying to focus on how the OpenGL works, but for the time being my goal is to find the error that I'm making.

**Note:** 
I'm not sure whether such questions are acceptable in here, if so,please close it.

**Edit:**
I'm compiling the code using g++ with c++11.

Comment: Please don't add the C language tag if you're programming in C++.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm not sure, the functions "fprintf, printf, ..." are belong to C language and I generally use them, so that was the motivation for me to add C language. I mean I'm originally a C programmer, and I do that a lot.

Comment: You're programming in C++, you use header files which are C++-only, you use expressions and literals that are C++-only. Even though you use older functions that come from C, you're still program in C++. So that's the only tag you should use.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I see, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The triangle you try to draw is outside of the visible area. By default (that means without any projections/transformations applied), the visible area goes from -1 to 1 on all three axis. The triangle used in the code does not intersect this area, thus nothing gets rendered.

Besides that: You are calling the `glColor3f` function which is deprecated in a core profile. This should report a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` which you are most probably not seeing because error checking only happens when the renderloop has ended. You should really check for errors somewhere inside the renderloop.

Comment: I actually thought about it, but I did not know that the visible range varies between -1 and 1 in all axis. Thanks a lot.